# Windows Mouse Hook Causes lag on console

Tags: c, windows, winapi, hook, lag

I have set up a low level mouse hook. Now i am logging the events in the console. What is happening is when i try scrolling the console using the scrollbar the mouse starts lagging! I cannot see any high CPU usage so as far ad I can guess it is due to the events not being forwarded.

Here is the relevant code:

```
HHOOK mouseHook = SetWindowsHookExA(WH_MOUSE_LL, (HOOKPROC)mouse_hook, handle, 0);
MSG msg;
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) != 0)
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
UnhookWindowsHookEx(mouseHook);
```

And,

```
LRESULT CALLBACK mouse_hook(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    MSLLHOOKSTRUCT *data = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT *)lParam;
    POINT mouse_point = data->pt;
    unsigned long mouseX = mouse_point.x;
    unsigned long mouseY = mouse_point.y;
    unsigned long timeStamp = data->time;
    unsigned long flag = data->flags;
    printf("mouse_hook :\nPOS: (%ld, %ld)\nTimeStamp: %ld\n\n", mouseX, mouseY, timeStamp);
    switch(wParam){
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:{
            break;
        }
        case WM_LBUTTONUP:{
            break;
        }
        case WM_MOUSEMOVE:{
            break;
        }
        case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:{
            break;
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: The Windows console is notoriously slow and blocks `printf()`. You might want to decouple the writing and the showing of the log messages.

Comment: Start with the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644986(v=vs.85)). Read it. Thoroughly. As implemented, you are logging noise, you shouldn't be handling altogether.

Comment: Nothing obvious, this should not cause noticeable lag.  It is very suspicious code, especially with an .exe file appearing from seemingly nowhere, be sure to disable any installed security software.

Comment: @HansPassant i do not have any security software installed1 and also i usually disable windows defender while testing these.

Comment: @IInspectable thanks for suggesting the the docs(i will go through it). And for what i am logging is just to check whether everything is setup correctly(this wont be there in final code).

Comment: Here is the relevant section from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644986(v=vs.85)): *"If `nCode` is less than zero, the hook procedure must pass the message to the `CallNextHookEx` function **without further processing**"*.

Comment: @IInspectable in all cases it is passed to `CallNextHookEx ` (in my example). And what is meant by further processing?(Like i am just printing the parameter values i don't think this counts as an processing)

Comment: *"i am just printing the parameter values"* - Those values aren't even guaranteed to be meaningful. Since you already know, that console output is slow, why reject advice that suggests to reduce the number of calls that are known to be slow? I mean, it literally takes less than a minute to verify, whether this changes anything, so why not try?

Comment: @IInspectable yeah removing the prints just fixes this! so it is sure that the problem is with the console output! Thanks!

Comment: I wasn't suggesting to remove the console output altogether. Just remove the console output whenever `nCode` is less than zero, i.e. `if (nCode >= 0) { /* log values */} return CallNextHookEx(...);`.

Comment: @IInspectable i tried what you suggested(print only if nCode>=0) but that too causes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in comments, calling `printf` inside such a frequent callback function will be an issue. `printf` and the Windows console API in general are slow functions.

If you need this logging feature, then:

- Create a separate thread which does all printing.
- Create some manner of FIFO queue which is accessed thread-safe, by using mutex or critical section.
- Have the mouse callback put struct items in the queue and have the print thread remove them.
- Optionally, you can have the print thread asleep when there is no work, then have the mouse callback wake it up by setting an event.

Comment: A lock-free queue is almost trivial to implement. No need for some heavy-handed machinery just to make a FIFO queue thread compatible.

Comment: Plus, this answer is failing to acknowledge a crucial detail: A low-level mouse hook must only process *some* of its input. The rules are spelled out in the documentation.

Comment: @IInspectable So why not post an answer of your own instead of whining?

Comment: Why call it *"whining"*? Did I hit a soft spot?